# How to multithread with threads generated in a loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

So I'm writing code that will parse through multiple text files in a folder, gather information on them, and deposit that information in two static List instance variables. The order of which the information is deposited does not matter since I will end up sorting it anyways. But for some reason, increase the number of threads does not impact the speed. Here's my run method and the portion of my main method that utilizes multithreading.

```
public void run() {
    parseFiles();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (filesLeft != 0) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new fileParser());
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("error.");
        }
}
```

If extra information is required, I basically have a static instance variable as an array of the files I need to go through, as well as a constant being the number of threads (which is manually changed for testing purposes). If I were to have, say, 4 threads and 8 files, each call to parseFiles goes through the next 2 files of the array, the indices being monitored by a static instance variable. If I had, say, 4 threads and 9 files, the first thread parses 3 files, the following parse 2, with a statement something along the lines of `filesToParse = Math.ceil(filesLeft / threadsLeft)`, the latter two variables within the ceiling function being static as well.

Is there any error in my code or should I simply be testing larger text files with more words to see a decrease in speed with added threads (currently I have 5 text files each with 20+ paragraphs and I get around 60-70ms).

Comment: "But for some reason, increase the number of threads does not impact the speed" You start a thread then immediately block and wait for it to complete.

Comment: Is it because I call join on the thread? That's what I thought previously, but if I take out the join() then the whole main class never stops running. At some point, don't I need to join all the threads? How would I do that if they're generated in the for loop?

Comment: You need to start all threads first, then you can wait for them to finish, so you need to keep track of them somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote a list piece of code that might be useful

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    final List<Runnable> tasks = generateTasks(NUM_TASKS);
    List<Thread> threadPool = new LinkedList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Runnable task = null;
            while ((task = getTask(tasks)) != null) {
                task.run();
            }
        });
        threadPool.add(thread);
        thread.start();
    }

    for(Thread thread: threadPool) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long runTimeMs = (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000;
    System.out.println(String.format("Ran %d tasks with %d threads in %d ms", NUM_TASKS, NUM_THREADS, runTimeMs));
}

private static Runnable getTask(List<Runnable> tasks) {
    synchronized (tasks) {
        return tasks.isEmpty() ? null : tasks.remove(0);
    }
}
```